# Is an image there? if so carry on. If not keep checking

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a button `#myButton` that has a link to an image that will be created by a PHP script `createImage()`. I need to fire the `createImage()` and then check to see if the image is there `isImgThere(imageLink);`.

The problem is that my code just runs through the `isImgThere(imageLink)` function and does not wait until true before the link is triggered. How do I get the `isImgThere(imageLink);` function to finish only when `success`? I have tried using `while` statements but none have worked.

```
$('#myButton').on('click', 'img', function() {
    createImage(size);
    isImgThere(imageLink);
});

function isImgThere(imageLink) {
    $.ajax({
        url:imageLink,
        type:'HEAD',
        error: function()
        {    
            alert("false");
            return false;
        },
        success: function()
        {    
            alert("true");
            return true;
        }
    });
}
```

This is the create an image function:

```
function createImage(size) {
    var myImage = ZoomAddress + 'php/zoom.php';
    var myPram='random='+random+'&returntype=3&size='+size+'&Views='+imgViews+'&'+WhatZoom;
    $.post(myImage,
        myPram,
        function(data) {

    });
}
```

Comment: Would you not add a callback to the `createImage()` method instead, triggered when the PHP script is done and sends a response?

Comment: Setting actions from async callbacks is one of the more challenging aspects of js programming. This is the sort of thing promises are meant to address ( https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise ), but they're not supported on nearly enough browsers yet to rely on.
Like Marty says, you should probably just call createImage() from your callback.

Comment: Can you post the `createImage` function?

Comment: just done so Marty, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should make use of the response callback for a cleaner approach; something like:

```
function createImage(size, done)
{
    var params = {
        random: random,
        returntype: 3,
        size: size,
        Views: imgViews
    };


    $.post(ZoomAddress + 'php/zoom.php', params, done);
}
```

Which would be used in your case like:

```
$('#myButton').on('click', 'img', function()
{
    createImage(size, function()
    {
        // Image is there.
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks Marty, do I have to add code to my PHP? I will read up on callbacks

Comment: @user2238083 No, you won't need to add code to the PHP.

Comment: Thanks, sorry if I'm missing something but how do I get the code to wait here "// Image is there." until the image is there?

Comment: yes I see:
$('#myButton').on('click', 'img', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();  //stop the browser from following
        createImage(size, function(e)
            {
                
                window.location.href = imageLink;
                
            });
    });